# Could the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle turn out to be false?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-entanglement, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, epr-experiment

While investigating the [EPR Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epr_paradox), it seems like only two options are given, when there could be a third that is not mentioned - Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle being given up.

The setup is this (in the wikipedia article): given two entangled particles, separated by a large distance, if one is measured then some additional information is known about the other; the example is that Alice measures the z-axis and Bob measures the x-axis position, but to preserve the uncertainty principle it's thought that either information is transmitted instantaneously (faster than light, violating the special theory of relativity) or information is pre-determined in hidden variables, which looks to be not the case.

What I'm wondering is why the HUP is not questioned? Why don't we investigate whether a situation like this does indeed violate it, instead of no mention of its possibility? Has the HUP been verified experimentally to the point where it is foolish to question it (like gravity, perhaps)?

## Edit

It seems that all the answers are not addressing my question, but addressing waveforms/commutative relations/fourier transforms. I am not arguing against commutative relations or fourier transforms. Is not QM the theory that particles can be represented as these fourier transforms/commutative relations? What I'm asking this: is it conceivable that QM is wrong about this in certain instances, for example a zero state energy, or at absolute zero, or in some area of the universe or under certain conditions we haven't explored? As in:

Is the claim then that if momentum and position of a particle were ever to be known somehow under any circumstance, Quantum Mechanics would have to be completely tossed out? Or could we say QM doesn't represent particles at {absolute zero or some other bizarre condition} the same way we say Newtonian Physics is pretty close but doesn't represent objects moving at a decent fraction of the speed of light?

## Example

**EPR Paradox:** "It considered two entangled particles, referred to as A and B, and pointed out that measuring a quantity of a particle A will cause the conjugated quantity of particle B to become undetermined, even if there was no contact, no classical disturbance."

"According to EPR there were two possible explanations. Either there was some interaction between the particles, even though they were separated, or the information about the outcome of all possible measurements was already present in both particles."

These are from the wikipedia article on the EPR Paradox. This seems to me to be a false dichotomy; the third option being: we could measure the momentum of one entangled particle, the position of the other simultaneously, and **just know both momentum and position** and beat the HUP. However, this is just 'not an option,' apparently.

## Clarification

I'm not disputing that two quantities that are fourier transforms of each other are commutative / both can be known simultaneously, as a mathematical construct. Nor am I arguing that the HUP is indeed false. I'm looking for justification not just that subatomic particles can be models at waveforms under certain conditions (Earth like ones, notably), but that a waveform is the only thing that can possibly represent them, and any other representation is wrong. You van verify the positive all day long, that still doesn't disprove the negative. It is **POSSIBLE** that waveforms do not correctly model particles in all cases at all times. This wouldn't automatically mean all of QM is false, either - just that QM isn't the best model **under certain conditions**. Why is this not discussed?

Comment: I +1d to get rid of the downvote you had. It's the last line that did it for me.

Comment: Anyone who is downvoting care to elaborate on where my question is unclear, unuseful or shows no effort? I'd be glad to improve it if I can.

Comment: Try Bohmian mechanics.

Comment: @Ehryk: Not my downvote, but this question is a waste of time. You misunderstood what EPR is all about. The EPR effects have nothing to do with HUP, and you can show that they are inconsistent with local variables determining experimental outcomes _without doing quantum mechanics_, just from the experimental outcomes themselves. This means the weirdness is not due to the formalism, but really there in nature.

Comment: So in a universe without the commutative relation/HUP, where the commutative relation was sometimes zero / position and momentum could both be known, where's the paradox with EPR? You could just determine the values of both entangled particles, no paradox necessary.

Comment: I'm still awaiting the extraordinary evidence for the extraordinary claim.

Comment: @Ehryk: how about the whole of particle physics, all of which is dependent on this?  What would you non-HUP explanation of the electron double slit experiment be?  How about an explanation of how electron microscopes work?  You appear to be deliberately obtuse.  And saying "what if X?" as a counterexample to well-established physics when X is plainly physically impossible is a useless rejoinder.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35972/2451

Comment: upvote because there are 13 answers and hundred comments all interesting, it's a great page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In precise terms, the Heisenberg uncertainty relation states that the product of the expected uncertainties in position and in momentum of the same object is bounded away from zero.

Your entanglement example at the end of your edit does not fit this, as you measure only once, hence have no means to evaluate expectations. You may claim to know something but you have no way to check it. In other entanglement experiments, you can compare statistics on both sides, and see that they conform to the predictions of QM. In your case, there is nothing to compare, so the alleged knowledge is void.

The reason why the Heisenberg uncertainty relation is undoubted is that it is a simple algebraic consequence of the formalism of quantum mechanics and the fundamental relation $[x,p]=i\hbar$ that stood at the beginning of an immensely successful development. Its invalidity would therefore imply the invalidity of most of current physics.

Bell inequalities are also a simple algebraic consequence of the formalism of quantum mechanics but already in a more complex set-up. They were tested experimentally mainly because they shed light on the problem of hidden variables, not because they are believed to be violated.

The Heisenberg uncertainty relation is mainly checked for consistency using Gedanken experiments, which show that it is very difficult to come up with a feasible way of defeating it. In the past, there have been numerous Gedanken experiments along various lines, including intuitive and less intuitive settings, and none could even come close to establishing a potential violation of the HUP.

Edit: One reaches experimental limitations long before the HUP requires it. 
Nobody has found a Gedankenexperiment for how to do defeat the HUP, even in principle. We don't know of any mechanism to stop an electron, thereby bringing it to rest. It is not enough to pretend such a mechanism exists; one must show a way how to achieve it in principle. For example, electron traps only confine an electron to a small region a few atoms wide, where it will roam with a large and unpredictable momentum, due to the confinement. 
Thus until QM is proven false, the HUP is considered true. Any invalidation of the foundations of QM (and this includes the HUP) would shake the world of physicists, and nobody expects it to happen.

Comment: Why wouldn't it just invalidate it under certain conditions? For example: by some means, we completely arrest an electron. Position = center of device, momentum = 0. Both known simultaneously. Couldn't we just say QM is 'not a valid model for arrested particles but works for moving ones' without invalidating most of current physics?

Comment: Any invalidation of the foundations of QM would shake the world of physicists. - But the center of a device is usually poorly definable, and an electron cannot be arrested completely, neither in position nor in momentum. One reaches experimental limitations long before the HUP requires it. - In the past, there have been numerous Gedanken experiments along similar and many other lines, and none could even come close to establishing a violation of the HUP.

Comment: In practice, I get this. I'm not claiming that we can make such a machine now, or soon. But the HUP seems to say such a machine cannot exist, now or ever, with more advanced races or technologies or anything. Are you saying an electron cannot be arrested completely - anywhere, ever, inside a black hole, at absolute zero - under no conditions ever?

Comment: Nobody has found a Gedankenexperiment for how to do it in principle. We don't know of any mechanism to stop an electron, thereby bringing it to rest. It is not enogh to ask for doing it, you need to give a way how to achieve it in principle. Electron traps only confine the electron to a small region a few atoms wide, where it will roam with a large and unpredictable momentum, due to the confinement.

Comment: So until proven false, the HUP is true?

Comment: until QM is proven false, the HUP is true.

Comment: Can you clarify how different that statement is from "Until proven otherwise, the Flying Spaghetti Monster created the universe from his noodly appendage", or any other faith statement? What else in science is 'true until debunked'?

Comment: P.S. if you can put that as an edit to your answer, perhaps with a synopsis of these comments, the bounty is yours.

Comment: Physics is not about Flying Spaghetti Monsters. But I added part of the discussion at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Ehryk: here's why you're seeming nonsensical to everyone here: at small length scales, an electron looks very, very much like a wave.  You get interference patterns and everything.  Now, you want to 'stop' it. Well, a "slower" electron has a longer wavelength than a "faster" one, but this longer wavelength is going to spread it out farther.  By the time you get to your limit of a 'stopped' electron, the electron will be spread out over all of space.

Comment: Sure, in the context of medium temperatures, medium gravity, low strength electromagnetic fields on earth, yes, the electron seems to be behave like a wave. I've got that. But THEN to turn it around and say `Therefore the electron can ONLY be modeled as a wave, ALWAYS, in black holes, at absolute zero, in hyper-strength electric fields, always and forever and never deviates EVER` is the part that is an extraordinary claim which I have yet to hear conclusively justified. It does not seem to follow from the evidence. Electron can be modeled as a wave sometimes = True. Electron IS ONLY a wave...?

Comment: @Ehryk: So you're asking "If we subject things to conditions beyond our current experimental limits, and find something unexpected there, will theory have to be adjusted in unexpected ways?"  It's almost a tautology.

Comment: NO! I'm asking "How are we able to assert the unquestioning truthness of HUP in these areas?" Isn't HUP **at best** just the closest to what we observe when we can observe things? It should not be "True until debunked", just "Likely true for what we can observe so far." HUP far surpasses that level in its aspirations.

Comment: @Ehryk: Most researchers don't have time to waste. They therefore start asking questions about the validity of a principle only after there are actually signs that it might be invalid. Currently there is not a single such sign. That's enough to trust the principle. Hardly anybody asserts that the principle must remain true under all conceivable unobserved conditions.

Comment: Then why must it hold true for the entangled particles in the EPR Paradox? Why not say the measurement of one breaks the entanglement/waveform, or just that one can 'beat' the HUP this way? Instead we say 'no way, the HUP is OBVIOUSLY true, so therefore this is a PARADOX'.

Comment: @Ehryk: Most physics is done on the basis that QM is correct. Under this premise, the HUP must hold, as it is OBVIOUSLY a consequence of it. Thus it is taken for granted by most people, but almosst never in the extreme formulations that you are using.

Comment: I, for one, would just like it clarified more explicitly and often that we're assuming QM to be correct, an assumption which itself assumes additional assumptions. Then the EPR 'Paradox' would read: {option 1 (local variables)} {option 2 (FTL information travel)} OR {QM is not correct}.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer "an electron looks very, very much like a wave". That sounds fine, until you start saying therefore it IS a wave. The shadow of a man can look very, very much like a woman, except when you turn the lights on, he isn't. I'm asking for justification between the 'well, on some experiments on earth an electron behaves like a wave' to 'an electron is a wave'. Accordingly, when we run into something a wave cannot do, like stop, why we then associate this characteristic with an election and say an electron cannot stop. I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm asking why it's assumed right.

Comment: The obvious alternative I'm pushing for discussion here is: an electron behaves like a wave under certain conditions as far as we can tell now, but may not always be represented by a waveform under all cases. This way the contradictions with bringing one to rest that are inherent to the wave interpretation may not contradict a particle from stopping under all circumstances, and I'm not just quoted things like fourier transforms and commutation relations, properties inherent to waves, when I'm discussing a particle that may or may not be a wave.

Comment: @Ehryk: "it's not 'on some experiments' it's 'on all known experiments and observations' ".  There are no known contradictions with quantum mechanics.  You coudl perhaps come up with some non-QM way to describe the electron, and perhaps if you were very clever, you could come up with some way to match the results of every experiment ever done, and maybe this theory would make sense of a "stopped" electron.  But that hasn't been done, and QM has been very, very successful in describing all known experiments and predicting the results of experiments not done when the theory was written down.

Comment: @Ehryk: sure.  Under circumstances not observed, maybe anything could happen.  There's just no reason to believe that will be the case.  The default assumption should be that things we havne't observed will act like things we have observed.

Comment: Physics doesn't really care what is true, only what is useful.

Answer (score 9):

The Heisenberg's relation is not tied to quantum mechanics. It is a relation between the width of a function and the width of its fourier transform. The only way to get rid of it is to say that x and p are not a pair of fourier transform: ie to get rid of QM.

Comment: So if by any means at all (entanglement, future machines, or divine powers) one could measure both position and momentum simultaneously, then all of quantum mechanics is false? There could be no QM in a universe in which this is possible?

Comment: You necessarily need to change the relationship between position and momemtum. It is mathematically impossible if they just form a fourier transform pair. But considering the huge amount of datas validating QM, one can try to extend QM by adding a small term in the pair or by using a fractional commutator (with fractional derivative) for instance.

Comment: How about saying x and p are a pair of fourier transforms USUALLY, but not in certain circumstances such as `{inside a black hole, at absolute zero, under certain entanglement experiments, in a zero rest energy universe, etc.}` How do we know that because QM is right USUALLY or from what we can observe, that it is right ALWAYS and FOREVER?

Comment: That is to say: QM as we know it is not valid in these cases. There is no possible objections to such a statement, but for it to get accepted by the physicists, you need to prove that you can explain things in a simpler way and that you can predict something measurable.

Comment: Then why is there not a third option in the EPR Paradox as quoted above, in the entanglement setup, you just get to know the momentum of particle A and position of particle B, thereby beating the HUP? It's just taken off the table as an option, and I'm not sure why?

Comment: Because there is no proof whatsoever that QM fails. The day it fails we shall reconsider the question. However, there are many theorists working on alternative theories, so you have your chances.

Comment: So just accept it as true until it's proven wrong? Sounds like the Flying Spaghetti Monster argument. And why does it need to be 100% right or completely wrong? Special relativity didn't 'prove Newton wrong,' it just improved the accuracy of the equations when measuring things Newton could not possibly have measured.

Comment: @Ehryk given that there is a mountain of evidence in favor of it (not the case with FSM), then yes, we accept it as true until proven wrong (and of course by "proven wrong" I mean in some limited domain, just as Newtonian mechanics was "proven wrong" by SR).

Comment: Sounds like a faith position to me. 'Accepting it as the most likely model of the limited amount of reality that we can observe' would be the more scientific approach rather than 'accept it as true, anything that contradicts it is de facto false.' The difference would be that in the former case, it's still up for discussion, the latter it isn't (which is what I observe to be the case).

Comment: Reading these lines seem to imply that it is still up for discussion. Physicists are kind of schizophrenic: they don't like when someone changes their habits and theories but they keep working on writing down/changing theories...

Comment: 'Accepting it as the most likely model of the limited amount of reality that we can observe' would be the more scientific approach rather than 'accept it as true'. You are right, but from a psychological point of view, that would force scientists to remember they might be wrong. Physics studies are long and difficult and jobs at the end are scarce, once you get on the top, you are lost for humility. It takes 20 more years to aknowledge that you just don't know nothing, and very few get to that point. Most are busy building a shrine to their glory.

Answer (score 7):

In quantum mechanics, two observables that cannot be simultaneously determined are said to be *non-commuting*.  This means that if you write down the commutation relation for them, it turns out to be non-zero.  A commutation relation for any two operators $A$ and $B$ is just the following  $$[A, B] = AB - BA$$  If they commute, it's equal to zero.  For position and momentum, it is easy to [calculate the commutation relation](http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/quantum/style_a/commute.html) for the position and momentum operators.  It turns out to be $$[\hat x ,\hat p] = \hat x \hat p - \hat p \hat x = i \hbar$$  As mentioned, it will always be some non-zero number for non-commuting observables.  So, what does that mean physically?  It means that no state can exist that has both a perfectly defined momentum and a perfectly defined position (since $ |\psi \rangle$ would be both a right eigenstate of momentum and of position, so the commutator would become zero.  And we see that it isn't.).

So, if the uncertainty principle was false, so would the commutation relations.  And therefore the rest of quantum mechanics.  Considering the mountains of evidence for quantum mechanics, this isn't a possibility.

**Addition**

I think I should clarify the difference between the HUP and the classical [observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28physics%29).  In classical physics, you also can't determine the position and momentum of a particle.  Firstly, knowing the position to perfect accuracy would require you to use a light of infinite frequency (I said wavelength in my comment, that's a mistake), which is impossible.  See [Heisenberg's microscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg%27s_microscope).  Also, determining the position of a particle to better accuracy requires you use higher frequencies, which means higher energy photons.  These will disturb the velocity of the particle.  So, knowing the position better means knowing the momentum less.

The uncertainty principle is different than this.  Not only does it say you can't determine both, but that the particle literally doesn't have a well defined momentum to be measured if you know the position to a high accuracy.  This is a part of the more general fact in quantum mechanics that it is meaningless to speak of the physical properties of a particle before you take measurements on them.  So, the EPR paradox is as follows - if the particles don't have well-defined properties (such as spin in the case of EPR), then observing them will 'collapse' the wavefunction to a more precise value.  Since the two particles are entangled, this would seem to transfer information FTL, violating special relativity.  However, it certainly doesn't.  Even if you now know the state of the other particle, you need to use slower than light transfer of information to do anything with it.

Also, Bell's theorem, and Aspect's tests based off of it, show that quantum mechanics is correct, not local realism.

Comment: So how do we know that all particles have a non-commuting relationship, always and forever, under all conditions, even the ones we aren't able to measure or with technology or knowledge we don't yet possess?

Comment: What if you define position and momentum as the two real numbers that you measure at time t from experiment?  (That's what most people consider "position" and "momentum" to be anyway.)  What is this "new" definition of position and momentum?

Comment: Let me add this:  I've taken QM and done those calculations for the commutation plenty of times to figure out what sets of compatible observables there are.  But I could give someone a random formula for some random integral and divide by 6.3 and say "look, this always comes out to a real value -- thus position and momentum can't be simultaneously well-defined!" and that makes no sense whatsoever.  Yeah, I know the  whole spiel  about eigenvalues and eigenstates and identical preparations of quantum systems, but what kind of *physical* experiment demonstrates this limit?

Comment: Noncommutativity of operators nicely explains emission spectra, which I believe were the subject of Heisenberg's (?) initial ponderings. There's a nice bit of this history explained at page 40 of this book by Alain Connes http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf (there is probably a more focused reference for this history, but I don't know of one)

Answer (score 4):

The wave formulation has in its seed the uncertainty relation.

Let me be precise what is meant by the wave formulation: the amplitude over space points will give information about localization on space, while amplitude over momenta will give information about localization in momentum space. But for a function, the amplitude over momenta is nothing else but the Fourier transform of the space amplitude.

The following is jut a mathematical fact, not up to physical discussion: the standard deviation, or the *spread* of the space amplitude, multiplied by the spread of the momenta amplitude (given by the Fourier transform of the former) will be bounded from below by one.

So, it should be pretty clear that, as long as we stick to a wave formulation for matter fields, we are bound *mathematically* by the uncertainty relation. No work around over that.

Why we stick to a wave formulation? because it works pretty nicely. The only way someone is going to seriously doubt that is the right description is to either:

1) find an alternate description that **at least** explains everything that the wave formulation describes, and hopefully some extra phenomena not predicted by wave formulation alone.

2) find an inconsistency in the wave formulation. In fact, if someone ever manages to measure both momenta and position for some electron below the Planck factor, it would be definitely an inconsistency in the wave formulation. It would mean we would have to tweak the De Broglie ansatz or something equally fundamental about it. Needless to say, nothing like that has happened

Comment: It's a mathematical fact IF the particle can indeed be wholly represented by that specific function, right? So in the entanglement experiment, perhaps that function does not represent the state of TWO entangled particles? Maybe we have entanglement wrong, or maybe that function does not represent particles in certain conditions? Why are these possibilities not even discussed?

Comment: @Ehryk, because scientists, as all humans, tend to do the least amount of effort that will get the job done, it really does not make economical sense to do otherwise. As i said, there would be something to discuss if something in the experiment would not turn out as expected, but it does. If you want to do your life's mission to prove false the wave representation, then you need to build an experiment that will either confirm it or disprove it. **then**, people will likely start seriously discussing other possibilities.

Comment: We can't prove Zeus doesn't exist, yet we don't accept his existence because of this. An idea shouldn't have to be 'debunked' to have a healthy amount of doubt in it, yet the wave formulation representing all particles, everywhere, at all times and locations seems to be presented 'beyond doubt' - so why is it stated with such certainty about unknowability and when challenged, the opposition gives in without so much as a mention?

Comment: (I'm not trying to prove it wrong, or stating that it is, I'm asking if it can be false and if so, why it's not treated as such)

Comment: @Ehryk, suppose someone starts asking why physicists assume that we only have one time dimension, and why we don't try to debunk that. We would reply the same thing; we have no reason to devote resources to debunk something that seems to fit so nicely with existing phenomena, so the ball is in the court of the person that insist that, say, two-dimensional time makes great deal of sense for X or Y experiment. Then, if the experiment sounds like something that has not been tested, and is under budget to implement, maybe some experimentalists will try to do it. That is how science works

Comment: But the existence of one time dimension doesn't cause all sorts of paradoxes, or tell us we cannot measure things, or necessitate that we abandon classical mechanics in all circumstances. You seem to be comparing my question with just asking random what ifs, but I just want to challenge the implicit certitude that the HUP/wavefunction model asserts unknowability across all particles, everywhere, at all times under all conditions, regardless of technology advances - with the only justification so far of "well, it works for the limited amount of things we tried" - insufficient for the claim.

Comment: if wave formulation is the right description, there is nothing unknowable about it. that uncertainty is really a spread of an actual wave function. The fact that there is randomness in the results does not imply that there is something unknown

Comment: If the wave formulation is the right description, the claim is that if position is known absolutely, momentum is UNKNOWABLE and if momentum is known absolutely, position is UNKNOWABLE. I have no issue with randomness.

Comment: if its randomness that you aren't comfortable with, think that even a classical universe with classical particles will have randomness, as can be seen from the following gedanken experiment: since your atoms are classical, i can copy each of them exactly, and make two exact copies of you, both believe to be you. What are your possible observations? 1) dying after being destructed 2) being teleported to 1st copy 3) being teleported to 2nd copy. It is in principle unknowable which one you will experience. quantum mechanics randomness is of this same exact nature

Comment: Huh? I have no quarrel with randomness. And why wouldn't there be a 4th possible observation: you made a copy of me, that thought he was me, and we both coexisted? Why would one have to die or be teleported?

Comment: you can't observe being in both, that does not make sense

Comment: I think you're making claims about the nature consciousness now that are unverified. Why can't I just observe you creating him, and he wakes up and starts observing me? Who cares? I don't even see how this relates to the HUP.

Comment: i've ask you "What are your possible observations". That question cannot have as answer your 4th option, because as a person you need to be in a single body. You cannot simply say "i coexist in both" since that is not something you will be able to experience. You'll experience just being teleported to one of the bodies, but not both

Answer (score 4):

You are asking if a more complete theory might show that HUP is wrong and that position and momentum do exist simultaneously. But a more complete theory has to explain all the observations that QM already explains, and those observations already show that position and momentum cannot have definite values simultaneously. This is known because when particles such as photon, electrons, or even molecules are sent through a pair of slits one at a time, an interference pattern on the detector plate appears that shows that the probability of the measured location and time follows a specific mathematical relationship. The fact that certain regions have zero probability shows that before measurement, the particles exist in a superposition of possible states, such that the wave function for those states can cancel out with other states resulting in areas of low probability of observation. The observed relationships through increasingly complex experiments rules out possibilities other than what is described by QM. The only way that QM could be superseded by a new theory is for new observations to be made that violate QM, but the new theory would still result in the same predictions as QM in the circumstances that QM has already been tested. Since HUP results directly from QM, HUP would also follow from a new theory with the only possible exception in conditions such as super high energy conditions such when a single particle is nearly a black hole.

Basically you have to get used to the idea that particles are really quantized fluctuations in a field and that the field exists in a superposition of states. Any better theory will simply provide additional details about why the field behaves in that way.

Comment: "Accept it as true until it's debunked" is not scientific. "**When** a particle can be perfectly represented by a waveform and ONLY a waveform, then it cannot have definite momentum and position" is acceptable. Asserting the "When" is "Always and Forever" is not.

Answer (score 3):

If we want the position and the momentum to be well-defined at each moment of time, the particle has to be classical. We inherited these notions from classical mechanics, where they apply successfully. Also they apply at macroscopic level. So, it is a natural question to ask if we can keep their good behavior in QM. Frankly, there is nothing to stop us to do this. We can conceive a world in which the particles are pointlike all the time, and move along definite trajectories, and this will "beat HUP". This was the first solution to be looked for. Einstein and de Broglie tried it, and not only them. Even Bohr, in his model, envisioned electrons as moving along definite trajectories in the atom (before QM). David Bohm was able to develop a model which has at a sub-quantum level this property, and in the meantime behaves like QM at quantum level. The price to be paid is to allow interactions which "beat the speed of light", and to adjust the model whenever something incompatible with QM was found. IMHO, this process of adjustments still continues today, and this looks very much like adding epicycles in the heliocentric model. But I don't want to be unfair with Bohm and others: it is possible to emulate QM like this, and if we learn QM facts which contradict it, it will always be possible to find such a model which behaves like QM, but also has a subquantum level which consists of classical-like point particles with definite positions and momenta. At this time, these examples prove that what you want is possible. One may argue that they are unaesthetic, because they are indeed more complicated than QM. But this doesn't mean that they are not true. Also, at this time they don't offer anything testable which QM can't offer. So, while QM describes what we observe, the additional features of hidden variable theories are not observable, more complicated, and violate special relativity. Or, if they don't violate special relativity, they contradict what QM predicts and we observed in experiments of entanglement like that of Alan Aspect. If EPR presents us with two alternatives, (1) spooky action at distance, (2) QM is incomplete, and that you propose, (3) HUP is false, let's not forget that Aspect's experiment and many others confirmed the alternative (1).

Now, it would be much better for such models if they would stop adjusting themselves to mimic QM, and predict something new, like a violation of HUP. This would really be something.

In conclusion, yes, you are right and in principle it is possible to beat HUP. The reason why most physicists don't care too much about this, is that the known ways to beat HUP are ugly, have hidden elements, violate other principles. But others consider them beautiful and useful, and if you are interested, start with Bohm's theory and the more recent developments of this.

---

**Update**

[Synopsis: The Certainty of Uncertainty](http://physics.aps.org/synopsis-for/10.1103/PhysRevLett.109.100404)

[Violation of Heisenberg’s Measurement-Disturbance Relationship by Weak Measurements](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v109/i10/e100404) ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0034))

Comment: This was rather helpful, so I appreciate it. I'm still just having difficulty wrestling with unknowability in relation to this; for example if we ever found a way to arrest a particle completely; we'd know it's position and momentum (0) both at the same time, and while it violated HUP, it could just be said 'this particle cannot be represented by a wavefunction.' The reach of the HUP seems to include this though, with no provisions, and just be accepted so OBVIOUSLY you can't stop a particle. Would we just say the particle is classical in that instance?

Comment: @Cristi I see (and generally have no objections to) your argument, but that conclusion seems misleading. Yes, it's possible to beat HUP (by discarding quantum mechanics) in the same sort of sense that it's possible to create a macroscopic stable wormhole: not strictly ruled out, but there is no evidence to support it. So I think it's misleading to be saying that this is possible.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: Thanks. To make clear my conclusion, and less misleading, I wrote the first, rather lengthy, paragraph. This contains for instance the statement "while QM describes what we observe, the additional features of hidden variable theories are not observable, more complicated, and violate special relativity." Anyway, I considered it would be more misleading to claim that one knows HUP can't be violated no matter what.

Comment: @Ehryk: In QM (and this is consistent with observations), the particle is not a point, with definite position and momentum. A good and pictorial explanation is to think at the particle as a wave. You mentioned Fourier analysis: you can't arrest a wave in a too small region, without making the corresponding "spatial frequency" (hence momentum) spread on a too large region ($\Delta x\Delta k_x\geq 2\pi$). From the wave mechanics viewpoint, (one version of) the HUP follows from Fourier analysis, by multiplication with Plank's constant.

Comment: What happened to particle-wave duality? Is QM discarding the particle-side of this, and electrons are only waves now? How does a wave have mass?

Comment: @Ehryk: "What happened to particle-wave duality?". Particles are represented as wavefunctions. They are defined on the full space, but may have a small support (bump functions). At limit, when concentrated at a point, bump becomes Dirac's $\delta$ function. Then, it has definite position $x$, but indefinite wave vector, so it spreads immediately (this corresponds to HUP). Its "dual" is a pure wave (with definite wave vector $k_x$, hence momentum $p_x$). The "particle-wave" duality refers to these two extreme cases. But most of the times the "wavicles" are somewhere between these two extremes.

Comment: @Ehryk: "How does a wave have mass?" They have momentum and energy: multiply wave 4-vector with $\hbar$ and obtain $4$-momentum, so yes, they have mass. Interesting thing: the rest mass $m_0$ is the same, even though in general the wave 4-vector is undetermined. By "undetermined" you can understand that the wavefunction is a superposition of a large (usually infinite) number of pure wavefunctions. Pure wavefunctions have definite wave vector (hence momentum), but totally undetermined position.

Answer (score 1):

"Heisenberg uncertainty principle" is a school term that is used in popular literature. It simply does not matter. What matters is the wavefunction and Schroedinger equation.

The EPR paradox experiment never used any explicit "uncertainty principle" in the proof.

Comment: As @MarkM pointed out above, what I meant but wasn't able to espouse was a 'non-commutation' property (a term I've not heard of in this context), or the claim that the exact position and momentum of a particle cannot be known simultaneously. I thought this was semantically equivalent to the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, which I guess it is not.

Comment: Also, from wikipedia: "The uncertainty principle is a fundamental concept in quantum physics." (from the disambiguation page, main article here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle ). Could you explain or give sources for it 'not matter'ing? Further, the wiki article on the EPR Paradox explicitly uses the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle - I'm not claiming WP is any authority, but it would be the source of my confusion.

Comment: Quantum mechanics is described by wave equations. There is nothing to add to that. Any desired "uncertainty principle" can be easily derived from the Schroedinger equation. On the other hand, the Schroedinger equations, entanglement and other QM principles cannot be derived from the "uncertainty principle". This makes the principle useless to any theoretic research beyond school-level illustrations.

Comment: @Annix This isn't true.  Firstly, Heisenberg's matrix mechanics is an equally valid formulation of QM as wave mechanics, see Zettlli page 3.  Second, the uncertainty principle is a part of wave mechanics.  As you say, you can easily derive it from the Schrodinger equation.  I find it odd that you say that this somehow makes the uncertainty principle irrelevant.  You can't simultaneously know position and momentum to perfect accuracy, since localizing the position of the particle involves adding plane waves, which then makes the momentum uncertain.

Comment: @Anixx If you claim that you may derive the HUP from the Schrödinger equation, you should show it. I actually think it is not possible, but I'm curious. One usually derive the HUP from the commutation relations and later one shows it is preserved by the unitary evolution. The Schr. equation tells us how the states evolve in time, while the HUP must be verified even in the initial state so I'm very skeptical about your derivation. In any case, the HUP is at least as fundamental as the Schr. equation and it is a term very often used in technical papers and seminars.

Comment: @Anixx And of course you are not allowed to use $p\sim -i \partial _x$ because this follows from the canonical commutation relations, the general Schr. eq is $H|\Psi  >=i\partial _t |\Psi >$

Comment: @drake You can't derive it from the SE, but from the wave mechanics formulation (which is what I guess Annix means).  See the'Proof of Kennard Inequality using Wave Mechanics' sub-section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Wave_mechanics_interpretation  However, I agree with you that the HUP is fundamental (see my above post.).

Comment: @MarkM Ok, but that the wave form of SE is not more fundamental than the HUP in any way. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @drake Right, I 100% agree.  The HUP can be deduced from both wave mechanics and matrix mechanics, so it's quite clearly a fundamental part of QM.

Comment: Besides, if they used it, they would have other arguments to relativize the experimental results ( what's done by the defenders of the detection loophole )

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make Heisenberg's *principle* irrelevant is to measure the speed and the position (to make it simple) of a fundamental particle.

In other words, you would have to observe a particle, without having it collide with a photon or reacting to a magnetic force, or without interacting with it.

There might be an other way, which would be to find a very general law (but not statistical) which describes the characteristics (spin, speed, position etc) of an elemental particle in an absolute way....

Comment: I think that's just the observer effect, described in another answer, and I can beat that by hypothesyzing a future race that has developed a gravitational particle-position-and-momentum sensor machine, which does not use photons or interact with the particle in any way that would change the position or momentum (a read only sensor). Even in this case, the HUP says they CANNOT be known simultaneously.

Comment: I want to know what evidence there is to support this, even in the case of such a hypothetical machine.

Comment: In this case you interact using the gravitationnal interaction, so that's almost the same.

Comment: Not really. Bombarding it with photons are distinct events; surrounding it by a machine that is sensitive to the gravitation inside of it would only exert the same gravity that any other matter around it would, and if done as stated in my hypothetical, would not alter the position or momentum in any way once the particle has settled inside the machine.

Comment: Very interesting, and it would be possible if such a machine existed (my first point). But how would you measure something else than a change in the surronding gravitationnal field (which would imply an interaction with the particule) and how would you measure a spin ? It sounds like your method is equivalent to trying to measure an absolute quantity of energy, or to "forcing" the position or momentum of your particle, a case which doesn't fall under Heisenberg's principle.

This reasoning might end up as a Ouroboros..

Comment: Some clarification: I'm not discussing Heisenberg probability law, but just the principle, and it's similar to the observer effect because Heisenberg used this effect as a base for his work.

Comment: Do you have a link to a good article on the EPR Paradox ? The one on Wikipedia is not very good, on Bell's inequality.

Comment: No, do you have one that you recommend?

Comment: I wouldn't need to measure spin, just position and momentum. Further, 'forcing' position AND momentum does fall under the HUP. The change in gravitational field is not necessarily an interaction with the particle - it's changing the gravitational field by some small amount as it rotates, and is influenced by the gravity of everything around it - none of this is considered 'interacting.' A machine that detects this minute change could conceivably exist sometime, but the HUP says it cannot exist.

Comment: I think you would have to know the spin to know the momentum because the spin is linked to the angular momentum. If you don't, you will only have the linear speed of the particule, not its momentum (so you could'nt predict how it would collide with another particle for example).

The HUP assumes measurement or observation of a particule can only be made by interacting with it at some level (either seeing it, or feeling it like you propose, and using the gravitationnal force would be an interaction). That's why I said in my answer 'make the HUP irrelevant' rather than 'prove it's false'.

Comment: Momentum = mass * velocity. We know the mass of electrons. We could get the velocity by tracking it's position. The 'Observer Effect' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics) takes into discusses destroying the system by measurement, but **the HUP says nothing of the sort**. The HUP is not about the observer, but says if a particle has a position, it DOES NOT HAVE A DEFINED MOMENTUM, and vice versa, regardless of my hypothetical measurement machine.

Comment: You talk about the linear momentum but it's not sufficient to describe the movement, you also need the angular momentum.

Concerning the HUP, it really considers the interaction (not the destroyment or the alteration). And if the particle has a position it may have a momentum, this momentum beeing only undetermined at the time of interaction, **precisely because you interact in a single process which is function of the time (speed)**. That's what I meant with interacting. You don't have to destroy or alter the state (that would'nt really be a problem).

Comment: To put it in a (maybe too simple) position/speed comparison : How do you measure a runner's speed ? You take a position, another one, measure the time, and divide.

Therefore you can't know precisely the speed at a precise time. The guy might as well rush like Usain then stop, take a nap, then reach your second position. This paradox might nearer than the observer thing.

Answer (score 1):

if can help

**Open timelike curves violate Heisenberg's uncertainty principle**

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5485v1.pdf

...and show that the Heisenberg uncertainty principle between canonical variables, such as position and momentum, can be violated in the presence of interaction-free CTCs....

**Foundations of Physics, March 2012, Volume 42, Issue 3, pp 341-361**

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.0433v2.pdf

...considering that a D-CTC-assisted quantum computer can violate both the uncertainty principle...

**Phys Rev Lett, 102(21):210402, May 2009**.

arxiv 0811.1209

...show how a party with access to CTCs, or a "CTC-assisted" party, can perfectly distin-
guish among a set of non-orthogonal quantum states....

**Phys. Rev. A 82, 062330 2010.**

arxiv 1003.1987v2

...and can be interacted with in the way described by this simple model, our results conﬁrm
those of Brun et al that non-orthogonal states can be discriminated...

...Our work supports the conclusions of Brun et al that an observer can use interactions with a CTC to allow them to discriminate unknown, non-orthogonal quantum states – in contradiction of the uncertainty principle...

.

Comment: It's also been shown that CTCs violate causality, that you can infer that something can appear out of nothing, that you can be the cause of yourself. That's why when are CTCs in a spacetime it is not considered a physically acceptable solution. Yes, if you find CTCs you can do anything. Violating HUP is not as bad as violating causality.

Answer (score 0):

Without gravity: The uncertainty principle is not really a principle because it is a derivable statement, it is not postulated. It is derivable and proven mathematically. Once you prove something you cannot unprove it. That means it cannot turn out to be false. For experimental verifications, see for example [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105061v1) by Zeilinger et al and the references inside. Zeilinger is a world expert on quantum phenomena and it is expected that he will get Nobel prize in the future.

With gravity, (and that matters only at extremely high energy, as high as the Planck scale): Intuitively you can use the uncertainty principle to give an estimate about the energy needed to resolve tiny region of space. For sufficiently small region in space you will create a black hole. So there is a limit on the spacial resolution one can achieve, because of gravity. If you try to use higher energy you will create a bigger black hole. Bottom line is, uncertainty principle does not make sense in this case because space loses its meaning and it cannot be defined operationally.

Comment: Things can be unproven if one of the axioms or postulates they are based on is proven false. HUP may be true if <x, y and z> are true, but it certainly is based on foundations (waveforms representing matter, for one) that are not infallible.

Comment: @Ehryk You cannot unprove something by changing the postulates, because then you are talking about totally different problem. You can compare only 2 situations giving the same postulates/axioms. The axioms are true and not false in the sense that the coherent structure coming out of those postulates leads to predictions that are consistent with experimental observations. The world is quantum mechanical.

Comment: You cannot unprove it as a model of how things could work, no, but you could show that it is just not the most accurate model of the world we live it - just like we can theorize about hyperbolic geometry as a model, though it's unlikely to be the model of reality. Is it the case that you could not have a variant of something like QM that produces similar results while in some instances allowing precise position and momentum values, in the same way newton's laws were 'good enough' for the values we had measured at non relativistic speeds up until that point?

Comment: @Ehryk No. You could not have had something similar to Newtonian meachanics that underlies Quantum Mechanics. What you are thinking of has been thought of for long time ago, it is unknown as hidden variables theories. It has been proven experimentally that something like Newtonian mechanics or any deterministic theory cannot be the basis of Quantum Mechanics. May be you should also keep in mind the following main point: QM is more general than CM, hence it is more fundamental. Since QM is more general than CM, one should understand how CM emerges from QM, not the other way around.

Comment: @Ehryk One should understand CM in terms of QM not QM in terms of CM.

Comment: I didn't ask if something could underlie QM, but the other way. I'm asking if this is possible... Newtonian Physics : Special Relativity :: Quantum Mechanics : Modified QM where position and momentum can be known in certain instances. In the same way SR comes up with nearly the same results that NP does for MOST calculations (with a caveat), could there not be any way to have a theory close to QM where HUP is not upheld?

Comment: It's not QM as a whole I'm having difficulties with, it's accepting unknowability. 'God Did It All' is more general than anything, should that be the basis of QM? More general != more correct. Am I forced to accept it to understand QM, or is there even a slight possibility the wavefunctions could be modified or defined differently?

Comment: @Ehryk The meaning of the word "understand" in physics is to discover/know the basic laws of nature, and to be able to use those law to explain different phenomenas and to make predictions. If you know the laws and can apply the laws to different situation, only then you can say you understand physics. There is no other meaning of the word understand in physics except that.

Comment: @Ehryk I answered you. You asked if this is possible and I explained to you that it is not possible, and it has been proven experimentally that it is not possible. Read the section on Bell's inequality from Griffiths's QM.

Comment: "it has been proven experimentally that it is not possible" -- what has? Because negative statements (especially those about impossibilities) are extraordinarily difficult to prove. It is a derivable fact that in a wave-form, certain values are non-commutative operators that are fourier transforms of each other. It has not been proven conclusively that a waveform is the only correct model of subatomic particles under all conditions everywhere in the universe and at all times. If it has, please provide sources.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, HUP cannot be disproven "at absolute zero", because absolute zero cannot be physically reached, er... due to HUP... is circular reasoning good enough? Let's try something else.

Maybe try to imagine what would happen if HUP was to be violated? For one, I guess the proton - electron charges would cause one or two electrons to fall down into the nucleus, as HUP normally prevents that (if the electron fell down on nucleus we'd know it's position with great precision, requiring it to have indeterminate but large momentum, so it kind of settles for orbiting around nucleus).

If you know more about the stuff than I do, try to imagine what else would happen, and how likely is that effect. For example, [if HUP violation would imply violation of 2nd law of thermodynamics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6894), this would render HUP violation pretty unlikely.

That much from a layman.

Comment: But then why can't we just say 'HUP is only for particles not at absolute zero'? It seems like violating it is 'not an option', even as above - so an electron falls into the nucleus. It has a measurable position and momentum. Why does HUP have to hold so strongly that we instead are comfortable with 'that particle must always have energy'?

Comment: The way I see it "absolute zero" is purely theoretical concept. Look up Bose-Einstein condensate, get a feeling for what happens at extremely low temperatures and then try to project that further to zero. Doesn't click.

So saying "HUP is only for particles at absolute zero" is like saying "HUP is for all particles", for absolute zero can't be reached.

Comment: Do you have evidence or citations that nothing can be absolute zero? Or are you just asserting it? Note that saying 'we can't get to absolute zero' is different than 'no particle anywhere, at any time, can be at absolute zero.'

Comment: Let me quote the beginning of Wikipedia entry on absolute zero :) "Absolute zero is the theoretical temperature at which entropy reaches its minimum value", note the word *theoretical*. 

Temperature always flows from + to -, so the simple explanation is: you'd have to have something *below* absolute zero to cool something else to absolute zero. (this would violate laws of thermodynamics).

Comment: Theoretical does NOT mean 'cannot be reached', just that it hasn't to our observation yet. The heliocentric model was theoretical until it was shown to be accurate. And no, you do not need colder matter to cool matter, you just need to cause energy to escape the matter to be cooled and concentrate somewhere else. You would just need the last bit of energy to escape the electron, so the electron stops rotating the nucleus.

Comment: How exactly will you transfer heat from hot to hotter, without interacting with the system in a way that will heat it up some more? If you can't accept laws of thermodynamics, I'm afraid I cannot contribute any more to the discussion.

Comment: Transfer heat from hot to hotter? Decrease the volume of the container. Cool matter? Increase the volume of the container. In both cases, heat is not 'transferred', but temperature (average kinetic energy) has been changed without the interaction of other matter, either hotter or colder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the Heisenberg Principle of Uncertainty is *not in any way* a result of technological limitations. This principle is an *inherent aspect of nature*. It is an undeniable truth. Just as justifiable as any other established property of nature. E.g. that quarks have mass.

I know that quantum mechanics is frighteningly counter-intuitive on a number of points. But you must stop trying to fight against something that is a property of nature, since the more you try the more you will fail. You cannot disprove something that is self evidently true. Just accept it as an *intrinsic property* of nature.

Comment: the principle might be improved and extended like any other. It is expressed through other concepts ( measure, space , time , states we believe as fundamental ) which may evolve themselves. It's the principle of research. How ? I don't know exactly. Who ? try a search for A Steinberg ( Toronto U. ) , for Y. Hasegawa ( Vienna U. Austria ) and for "weak and measurement" in scholar google ( 3 different approaches )

Answer (score -1):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle forms one of the most important pillars in physics. It can't be proven wrong because too many experimentally determined phenomena are a result of the uncertainty principle. However, something may be discovered in the future that can make a modification to the uncertainty principle - in a similar way that Newton's laws were modified by Einstein's special relativity. Saying that the uncertainty principle is wrong is like saying that Newton's law is wrong.

In reply to the comments,

I'm not saying that it can be falsified. It can't. In a classical sense, it will always be correct, in a similar way that Newton's law will always be correct.However, it can be modified. Until the day that all the open questions in physics have been resolved, how can you claim that the uncertainty principle can't be modified further?  Do we know everything about extra dimensions? Do we know everything about string theory and physics at the Planck scale?

By the way,  it has already been modified.

Please check this link.

http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0715

The uncertainty principle will always be correct. However, it can and has been modified. In its current formalism and interpretation,  it could represent a special case of a larger underlying theory.

The claim that the current formalism and limitations to the uncertainty principle are absolute and can never be modified under any circumstance in the universe, is a claim that does not obey the uncertainty principle itself.

Comment: The uncertainty principle is a lot closer to uncertainty law than your answer lets on.  It's not really about measurement so much as it's about a Fourier Transform.

Comment: The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is an unfalsifiable claim? All of (good) science is falsifiable. See the first paragraph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability

Comment: scientific and valuable answer ... Nature reported almost the same ( 2014 ? 2015 ? ) from specific lectures at the Perimeter Institute.