# How can one be 'certain' about anything that has an "Uncertainty Principle" at its core?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The **Uncertainty Principle**, which says that more than one aspect of a particle cannot be measured simultaneously, illustrates one of several major differences between quantum physics and classical physics. This idea, first presented by *Heisenberg*, takes into account that a miniscule bit of material can be either a particle or a wave, depending on the circumstance.

Actually, it is neither, until someone looks at it or an experiment forces it to pick sides. This means that a number of qualities aren't defined. If a scientist measures the speed of a particle, for instance, he can't measure position very accurately; it's as though quantifying one aspect puts the other aspects more out of focus. *Physicists* know this and try to compensate for it in their experiments. Still, the word **"uncertainty"** is there for a reason. Some *physicists* say this is not a principle at all and instead prefer to call the concept **"uncertainty relations"**.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: My question is the title itself.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The [uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson.E2.80.93Schr.C3.B6dinger_uncertainty_relations) is not a vague statement like "We cannot be sure about anything", but a precise statement about the variances of non-commuting operators, of which we can be certain.

Comment: I do agree with #ACuriousMind. But it is not prooved till a Scientist tries to prove it or use it in an expeiment ("it" refers to the system under consideration)

Comment: See my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/139187/59406), the uncertainty principle is a precise consequence of Fourier decomposition, there is even a purely classical analogue of it.

Comment: This is not a physics question: it's a philosophy question, and a rather uneducated one at that.

Comment: also, the "uncertainty principle" is a misnomer. The German original term "Unschärferelation" is probably better, it means "blurring relation" and just refers to the fact that the distributions cannot both be arbitrarily sharp.

Comment: Seems like a vague diatribe about the nature of quantum mechanics, void of a question.

Answer (score 1):

The uncertainty of something is a quantitative value. It is a number. The uncertainty principle is more named after this value of the uncertainty of a measurement because it is a relation between the uncertainty of two quantities. It is not named based on a lack of understanding. We could just as easily have called it something like the "Error Principle" or the "Variance Principle" or the "Precision Principle" or simply the "Heisenberg Principle". It's just a name that identifies a mathematical relation between the maximum precision of two measurements.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that we can be 'certain' about is [zero point energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy) in, for example, vibrations of atoms and molecules, which has been observed experimentally and is caused by the uncertainty principle.

So we can be certain and experimentally verify that the uncertainty principle is correct and that the theory which includes it is correct - is this helpful?