# Question on Heisenberg's uncertainty principle

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Can we measure limit of precision of measuring wavelength using [uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)? If yes how can we do that?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139178/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24068/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic : If we are given natural lifetime for decay and the wavelength it  emits. Can we find limit of precision of measuring wavelength? If there any equation for finding?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The wavelength of an emission line is not the proper physical quantity to characterize the system. The proper measurement would be the spectrum. The uncertainty principle does not put any restriction on the precision with which we can measure a spectrum.

Comment: Also, the uncertainty principle as is has nothing to do with measurement precision (it is a property of states) as explained in many answers including the above.