# Nuclear structure

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the protons and neutrons in the nucleus arranged in any particular way?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36469/are-the-protons-and-neutrons-in-the-nucleus-arranged-in-any-particular-way)

Isotopes have different numbers of neutrons. Essentially my question is: how does the addition of neutrons affect this structure if there is one?
*The reason this question is different is since it attempts to discuss how isotopes affect the structure of the nucleus, the other question discussed similar isotopes as far as I could tell.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35724/what-is-an-intuitive-picture-of-the-motion-of-nucleons and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36469/are-the-protons-and-neutrons-in-the-nucleus-arranged-in-any-particular-way

Comment: A look at the [nuclear shell model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model) will tell you that if you grasp (our current, limited understanding of) nuclear structure, you will see that adding neutrons will upset a nucleus' structure quite a bit.